# Extracting a database name from a file

Tags: java, performance, parsing

I am developing a project that converts SQL server file to MySQL file based on some assumptions. I have written a function that takes the string source as input and it extracts the database name. Is there any way to improve the code?

```
public String getDatabaseNameFromMySqlServerFile(String source) {

    String sourceFile = null;
    String databaseName = "";
    Path file = Paths.get(source);
    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader
            = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("create database")) {
                String[] Arrline = line.split(" ");
                for (String s : Arrline) {
                    if (!s.toLowerCase().equals("create") && !s.toLowerCase().equals("database")) {
                        databaseName = s;
                        return s;
                    }
                }
            }
            sourceFile = sourceFile + line;
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`databaseName` is a pointless local variable: you can simply delete all lines using it.

The same goes for `sourceFile`.

---

`Arrline` and `s` are poorly named variables, and `s` is lowercased twice:

> ```
> String[] Arrline = line.split(" ");
> for (String s : Arrline) {
>     if (!s.toLowerCase().equals("create") && !s.toLowerCase().equals("database")) {
>         return s;
>     }
> }
> ```

Cleaning these up the code becomes:

```
String[] segments = line.split(" ");
for (String origSegment : segments) {
    String segment = origSegment.toLowerCase();
    if (!segment.equals("create") && !segment.equals("database")) {
        return origSegment;
    }
}
```

---

The current method of extracting the database name is quite awkward and inefficient. Look at these steps:

- lowercase the line
- check if it contains a string
- split the line to tokens
- for each token

  - if the lowercased token is neither "create" nor "database" then return it

You can do much better using regular expressions:

```
Pattern DBNAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("create +database +(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

private String extractDatabaseName(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = DBNAME_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

The initialization of `line` is unnecessary,
because it gets assigned on the next line anyway:

> ```
> String line = null;
> ```

So a simple declaration is enough:

```
String line;
```

Comment: Very informative answer. I wasn't aware of the matcher class.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you really need to space that code, it is hard to read when there's no space. Also, because of the `try` block, the indentation is messing with my eyes. Try to keep it in one line, it would be easier to read, even if it is a little long line.

Appending strings together is **never** a good idea, it is heavy in terms of performance. You should use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). In fact, why do you keep the `sourceFile` string? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere. You should remove this line as it might be expensive on large files.

Also, I don't think you should catch the `IOException`. How do I know what happened if `null` is returned. Was it the file that was locked, non-existant, was there no `create table` in the script? Let the exception be, so people can catch it and do whatever they want with it. Catching it now seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: I think your second paragraph is a bit restricting. I guess I know what you mean, but your statement as is would criticize the (perfectly fine) implementation of `Object.toString()`.

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing. Though you get the point string concat using `+=` is worst than using the `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 3):

Using the native features of Java is important. Consider the new-to-Java8 features of a streaming file-by-line reader:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filepath))
```

That will process each line, as a line, in the stream. In Java 8 this would almost always be superior to a BUfferedReader and other wrappers on your file. You can then chain up the filters you want on it. I suggest using Regular Expressions, they are good for this. A pattern that looks like:

```
private static final Pattern DATABASE = Pattern.compile(
         ".*?\\bcreate\\s+database\\s+(\\S+).*",
         Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

That pattern will find `create database XXX` in the line, and remember whatever the `XXX` is, in group 1.

You can now convert each line in to a matcher, and filter those lines which match, and recall the database.

Additionally, the Streaming API is able to terminate when the first match is found. The code would all look like:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(filepath))
                .map(line -> DATABASE.matcher(line))
                .filter(Matcher::matches)
                .map(mat -> mat.group(1))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
```

That would need to be wrapped up in to a method that handles the IOException, and cleanly closes the file:

```
public static String locateDatabase(String filepath) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filepath))) {
        return stream
                .map(line -> DATABASE.matcher(line))
                .filter(Matcher::matches)
                .map(mat -> mat.group(1))
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```